# Excel VBA internet explorer automation to create a Google Calendar event

Tags: excel, vba, automation, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to automate the process of booking appointments into Google calendar through excel VBA.

I can open internet explorer but I can't get it to click on the (RED) "CREATE" button to allow me to enter my data and variables from excel.

I was trying to use GetElementByID() but couldn't find the ID in the source code.

Hope to hear from someone as this has really stumped me this time and I don't like being beaten by a challenge.

Comment: Hm, you maybe want to use the Google Calendar API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Comment: Use google's API, not an IE browser automation :)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out for myself today after two months of trying to figure it out. For some reason, looping through the div elements to find "Create" innerText and then click it doesn't work. However, the item index of the div container is 180 and if you specify that, then you can click it.

So here's the code that will click the "Create" button.

```
ie.document.getElementsByTagName("div").Item(180).Click
```